# How do I close a UI element when a tap occurs outside of it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

There are a lot of solutions to this problem floating around, but none of them seem to work properly for me. I have a button that opens a list of selections in a UI element, and I want it to close when clicked outside of it. I currently have this:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(gameObject);
}

public void OnDeselect(BaseEventData eventData)
{
    //Close the Window on Deselect only if a click occurred outside this panel
    if (!mouseIsOver)
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    mouseIsOver = true;
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(gameObject);
}

public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    mouseIsOver = false;
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(gameObject);
}
```

Which works fine on a PC, but unfortunately due to there not being an actual pointer on mobile, it closes the panel even if clicked inside. I have tried using something like this:

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        int id = touch.fingerId;
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(id))
        {
            isClicked = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Check if the mouse was clicked over a UI element
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                isClicked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

But that has not worked either. This seems like an incredibly simple problem and I don't understand why I can't find a simple solution to it.

Comment: `IsPointerOverGameObject` just means any object .. not necessarily the one you want to check for .. you probably could check for https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem-currentSelectedGameObject.html .. not sure though at which moment this would be changed ...

Answer (score 1):

I recomend using Unity technic when dropdown is created.

Look at this [link](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Dropdown.cs)

The main idea is to create blocker behind your button and the other ui elements.

Your open panel funcion should look something like this:

```
private RectTransform gameObjectTransform;
public void OpenPanel()
{
    CreateBlocker();
    gameObjectTransform = transform.parent;
    transform.SetParent(GetComponentInParent<Canvas>());
    transform.SetAsLastSibling();
}
```

Create blocker method like in docs:

```
private GameObject currentBlocker;
public void CreateBlocker()
{
    GameObject gameObject = new GameObject("Blocker");
    RectTransform rectTransform = gameObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    rectTransform.SetParent(ChatGraphics.Instance.mainCanvas, false);
    rectTransform.anchorMin = (Vector2)Vector3.zero;
    rectTransform.anchorMax = (Vector2)Vector3.one;
    rectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    Canvas canvas = gameObject.AddComponent<Canvas>();
    canvas.overrideSorting = true;
    canvas.sortingLayerID = component.sortingLayerID;
    canvas.sortingOrder = component.sortingOrder - 1;
    gameObject.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
    gameObject.AddComponent<Image>().color = Color.clear;
    gameObject.AddComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { Hide(); });
    currentBlocker = gameObject;
}
```

And last is Hide method which should be called every time (even if blocker does not triggered)

```
public void Hide()
{
    if (currentBlocker != null)
        Destroy(currentBlocker);
    if (gameObjectTransform != null)
        transform.SetParent(gameObjectTransform);
    // Your code to hide your panel
}
```